# Problemas com função str_pad e acentuação

Tags: php

Galera estou usando a função `str_pad` para pegar uma string e preencher ela com 10 caracteres `0`.

Está funcionando perfeitamente, veja o exemplo:

```
echo str_pad("dda", 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Ela escreve `0000000dda`.

O problema ocorre quando coloco acentuação, exemplo:

```
echo str_pad("ddã", 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Ao invés de escrever `0000000ddã` ele escreve `000000ddã`, ou seja ele perde um `0`. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: @VictorStafusa vc sabe o que pode ser, o problema?

Comment: Qual é o encode do arquivo? é aquela coisa a função `str_pad()` manipula bytes e não caracteres, caracteres acentuados ocupam 2 ou mais bytes por isso a string final fica com um caracter a menos. Fiz um teste aqui jogue um `utf8_decode()`  no primeiro argumento e funcinou. Deve outra forma melhor de resolver isso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que a função `str_pad` presume que cada caractere ocupa um byte. Quando você usa caracteres que têm mais de um byte de comprimento (como por exemplo o *ã*), a função começa a dar errado.

No StackOverflow em inglês [há uma pergunta sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14773072/540552) e lá há 4 respostas para esse problema. A julgar pelos comentários, duas das respostas têm problemas (inclusive a resposta aceita) e as outras duas devem ser adequadas (não as testei no entanto). Todas as respostas dadas lá consistem em criar uma função diferente capaz de lidar com caracteres multibytes.

Eis aqui [a solução do Wes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27194169/540552):

```
function mb_str_pad($str, $pad_len, $pad_str = ' ', $dir = STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding = NULL)
{
    $encoding = $encoding === NULL ? mb_internal_encoding() : $encoding;
    $padBefore = $dir === STR_PAD_BOTH || $dir === STR_PAD_LEFT;
    $padAfter = $dir === STR_PAD_BOTH || $dir === STR_PAD_RIGHT;
    $pad_len -= mb_strlen($str, $encoding);
    $targetLen = $padBefore && $padAfter ? $pad_len / 2 : $pad_len;
    $strToRepeatLen = mb_strlen($pad_str, $encoding);
    $repeatTimes = ceil($targetLen / $strToRepeatLen);
    $repeatedString = str_repeat($pad_str, max(0, $repeatTimes)); // safe if used with valid unicode sequences (any charset)
    $before = $padBefore ? mb_substr($repeatedString, 0, floor($targetLen), $encoding) : '';
    $after = $padAfter ? mb_substr($repeatedString, 0, ceil($targetLen), $encoding) : '';
    return $before . $str . $after;
}
```

Eis aqui [a solução do Ja͢ck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14773638/540552):

```
function mb_str_pad($input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding = 'UTF-8')
{
    $input_length = mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
    $pad_string_length = mb_strlen($pad_string, $encoding);

    if ($pad_length <= 0 || ($pad_length - $input_length) <= 0) {
        return $input;
    }

    $num_pad_chars = $pad_length - $input_length;

    switch ($pad_type) {
        case STR_PAD_RIGHT:
            $left_pad = 0;
            $right_pad = $num_pad_chars;
            break;

        case STR_PAD_LEFT:
            $left_pad = $num_pad_chars;
            $right_pad = 0;
            break;

        case STR_PAD_BOTH:
            $left_pad = floor($num_pad_chars / 2);
            $right_pad = $num_pad_chars - $left_pad;
            break;
    }

    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $left_pad; ++$i) {
        $result .= mb_substr($pad_string, $i % $pad_string_length, 1, $encoding);
    }
    $result .= $input;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $right_pad; ++$i) {
        $result .= mb_substr($pad_string, $i % $pad_string_length, 1, $encoding);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Isso acontece porque `ã` é um caractere [*multi-byte*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y9se58z.aspx), veja:

```
echo strlen("a"); // 1
echo strlen("ã"); // 2
```

A função [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php) interpreta `ã` como um caractere de dois *bytes* ao invés de um *multi-byte*, para contornar isso use a função [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strlen.php) para informar o tamanho da *string*, assim `ã` vai ser interpretado como um caractere *multi-byte*, veja:

```
echo mb_strlen("a"); // 1
echo mb_strlen("ã"); // 1
```

Você pode implementar `mb_strlen` deste modo ([**créditos**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#90611)):

```
function mb_str_pad( $input, $pad_length, $pad_string = ' ', $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT, $encoding = "UTF-8") {
    $diff = strlen( $input ) - mb_strlen($input, $encoding);
    return str_pad( $input, $pad_length + $diff, $pad_string, $pad_type );
}
```

Use assim:

```
echo mb_str_pad("ddã", 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // 0000000dda
echo str_pad("ddã", 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);    // 000000ddã
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/hyH8kY)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente resposta!! +1